# How to test a Wordpress plugin in real time

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a simple WordPress plugin, and each time I want to test the plugin manually, I need to make a zip file and upload it to the site through the admin panel. (The WordPress site is running locally through XAMPP) It's very tedious to do this every time I make a change.

Is there any way to test the changes to my plugin in real-time as I code? Helpful answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a local dev environment you can run WordPress and your plugin on your computer, any changes you make are instant as there is no uploading/installation step.

**Since you are already using XAMPP**, open the files directly with your editor from the XAMPP folder that contains the WordPress install. There is no need to upload and install as everything is on the same computer.